# as3 cs5 Odd Error #1009 in drag and drop game

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, flash-cs5

I'm making a drag-and-drop game. 
On the MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP I have an if-statement like so:

```
function fnUp(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        clicked.stopDrag();
        if (clicked.dropTarget.parent.parent.name == clicked.currentLabel)
        {
            var dropped:Card = clicked.dropTarget.parent.parent as Card;
            dropped.gotoAndStop(dropped.name);
            dropped.bg.gotoAndStop("done");
            removeChild(clicked);

        }
        else
        {
            clicked.x = clicked.sx;
            clicked.y = clicked.sy;
            clicked.bg.gotoAndStop("off");
        }
        clicked = null;
    }
```

"clicked" is an earlier declared var of type Card(); and it's set in the MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN like so:

```
    function fnDown(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        clicked = event.currentTarget as Card;
        clicked.bg.gotoAndStop("on");
        clicked.startDrag();
        addChild(clicked);
    }
```

I thought that if I build my if-statement like this there wouldn't be an error if the card was dropped anywhere but on one of the three possible target cards. But I still get:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

**tldr; I get an error if I drop my card outside one of the 3 possible targets.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which line you getting an error? You need to check if all of the following objects existing:

```
if (clicked.dropTarget &&
clicked.dropTarget.parent &&
clicked.dropTarget.parent.parent )
{
    then do something...
}
```

Comment: My dragged clip only has to do something when the condition applies I put in the if-statement: clicked.dropTarget.parent.parent.name == clicked.currentLabel . The error I'm getting I only get when I drop it outside one of the three possible droptargets on the stage, only there it shouldn't be able to react, because it should come under the else-part of the if-statement (am I making sense?)

Comment: you need to check the if all of the variables existing, because if for some reasons the `clicked.dropTarget` is `null` then you will not be able to get `clicked.dropTarget.parent` which will cause 1009 Error.

Comment: As I tried to explain, the if-statement works fine for the droptargets. Only, I get the 1009 error when I drop my 'clicked' outside the droptargets on the stage.

Comment: that's when one of the objects you have for calculations is `null`. Just trace all of the objects from the line where you get error.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see what you're trying to tell me :) I'll trace it all and get back to this Question when I've figured out. Thanks for your help!